# mysql search like with text うえ

Tags: mysql

when I search text 'うえ' it return include text 'ウェ'

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE content LIKE '%うえ%'
```

Some result not have any text 'うえ'

I don't know why. Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your string with N, By this SQl server know you using unicode characters

N actually stands for National language character set.

By this you pass **nvarchar** data type, rather than **varchar**

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE content LIKE N'%うえ%'
```

Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx)

**Why N Prefix?**

**Answer:**  Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This page may not recognize certain characters.

Comment: I use N after like, but it return the same result.

Comment: can u try for other keyword?